# Countability of Non-intersecting Disks, Circles, Figure Eights

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Synopsis**

Alas, I'm confused again.

I'm working through a problem set and I've come across the following exercise.

> (a) Let $A$ be a collection of circular disks in the plane, no two of
> which intersect. Show that $A$ is countable.
>
> (b) Let $B$ be a collection of circles in the plane, no two of which
> intersect. Need $B$ be countable?
>
> (c) Let $C$ be a collection of figure eights in the plane, no two of
> which intersect. Need $C$ be countable?

I have absolutely no idea how to approach this. How do I even define these shapes? Once I do define these shapes, how do I show countability? What does a proof look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINTS:

For (a), notice that every disk must contain a point of $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$.

For (b) consider concentric circles; what is the set of their possible radii?

(c) is a bit harder, but we can use a fancier version of the idea that I suggested for (a). For each of the figure eights we can pick a **pair** of points in $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$, one in each of the loops of the $8$. Now show that distinct $8$s cannot be associated with the same pair of points.

Comment: Hm... I'll think about your hints. Perhaps I just need to spend more time on it.

Comment: @mijucik: If you find yourself completely stuck, by all means ask, and I’ll see if I can push a little harder in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I had to do some chores around the house. For (a), would the following work? Let $R = \bigcup \{D \cap \mathbb{Q}^2 \mid D \in A\}$. Then $R \subseteq \mathbb{Q}^2$ and $|R| \leq \aleph_0$. Consider $G: A \rightarrow R$ where $G(D) = D \cap \mathbb{Q}^2$. Then since the disks are nonintersecting, $G$ is an injection. So $|A| \leq \aleph_0$.

Comment: For (b), would the argument go something like: Let $B$ be a set of concentric circles of increasing radii in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then the set $C = \{x^2 + y^2 = r \mid (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, r \in \mathbb{R}, r > 0\}$ would be uncountable.

Comment: For (c), I'm a bit stuck. How do I set a rule for which pair in $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ I pick? I'm guessing that if I'm to show that distinct figure-eights can't be associated with the same pair of points, I'm going to find a consistent method to find a point. But if I choose, perhaps, the center of each loop, isn't it possible that that center point will be an irrational pair?

Comment: @mijucik: The family of countable subsets of $\Bbb Q^2$ is uncountable, so your idea for (a) won't work, but it's easier than that anyway: just pick any rational point in the disk -- it can be in only one. And in (c) you really can use any pair of points, as long as one is in each loop. Your answer for (b), however, is fine.

Comment: Then would it be something like this? For (a), choose any rational point in $D \in A$. Then since the disks are nonintersecting, there is always a unique rational point for each $D$, and one can define an injection between $A$ and $\omega$ mapping each unique rational point in each member of $A$ to a unique number in $\omega$.

Comment: For (c), do you just choose do the same argument as in (a) but you map the two rational points to members of $\omega \times \omega$?

Comment: @mijucik: Yes, that works fine me (a), though since you know that $\Bbb Q^2$ is countable, you don't really even need to bring in $\omega$. And yes, (c) is essentially the same argument as (a), except that the countable set that you're using is now $\Bbb Q^2\times\Bbb Q^2$. The hardest part, and it's not really very hard, is explaining why two $8$s can't be associated with the same pair of rational points. (I'm shutting down for the night now, but I'll check back when I get up.)

Comment: For (c), then, to show that no two 8s can be associated with the same pair of rational points, would the argument be something like this? Suppose a figure eight shared a rational point with another figure eight. Then for the two figure eights not to intersect, one of the figure eights must be in the loop of the other for them to share a rational point. But then, the rational point in the other loop cannot be included in that figure eight without intersection. So no two figure eights contain the same rational points.

Comment: Also, thank you for your extended time today. Your continued help has really meant a lot, and I've come to be a little less afraid of asking for help. Goodnight.

Comment: @mijucik: Yes, that’s the argument for (c) that I had in mind. You’re very welcome. (Your questions are clear, and you think about the responses, so answering them is no hardship, believe me!)

Comment: For b, if circles be unit, can we say  such a set is uncountable? Thanks

Comment: @MohammadRostami: If they’re concentric, only one of them can be a unit circle.  But for any given point there are uncountably many circles with that point as centre, one for each positive real radius.

Comment: My question is, Let B be a collection of unit circles in the plane, no two of which intersect. Need B be countable?

Comment: @MohammadRostami: Yes: the interiors of those circles are pairwise disjoint open sets, so each must contain a different point of the countable dense set $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$.